# how to reset password into default using php

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, forgot-password

```
<?php 

 include("db_conection.php");  

if(isset($_POST['ForgotSubmit'])) 
{ 


    session_start();
    echo $admin_name=$_POST['admin_name'];  
         $pass_identity=$_POST['pass_identity']; 


    $admin_query="select * from admin where admin_name='$admin_name' AND pass_identity='$pass_identity'";
    $$sql = "UPDATE admin SET admin_pass='password' WHERE admin_name = '$admin_name'";

    $run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$admin_query);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)  
        {  
            if($admin_name == "admin"){
             echo "<script>alert('Your password is now set to *password*.'); window.location='Admin-Secu-Login.php'</script>";}

            if($admin_name == "security"){

            echo "<script>alert('Your password is now set to *password*'); window.location='Secy-Account-Details.php'</script>";}
        }  

    else {echo"<script>alert('Does not match.')</script>";}
    } 
?>
```

i would like to reset my password into default. First thing I need to do is answer correctly the security question but when I click on the button it doesnt not change in my database pls help

Comment: `$$sql`?!? You're using variable variables?

Comment: `SET admin_pass='password'` you do realize what you're doing here, right?

Comment: real nice sql injection we have here. Do you know of prepared statements? You should.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this line: `$$sql = "UPDATE admin SET admin_pass='password' WHERE admin_name = '$admin_name'";`(=> $sql) You have not used this command yet

...

```
if($admin_name == "admin"){
   $run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);  //add this line
         echo "<script>alert('Your password is now set to    *password*.'); window.location='Admin-Secu-Login.php'</script>";}
```

Comment: and what about the `$$`?

Comment: I've fixed it. He wants to reset the password to the default of the system.